New oven old home
I'm in the middle of a kitchen remodel and all is well but the oven wiring is giving me pause. I was about to move forward with hooking this up but knowing the prior owner did a lot of DIY as cheaply as possible I want to make sure this is safe.
Our very old farmhouse has the oven direct wired into a kitchen sub panel. The wires are black, white and bare copper.
The new oven has 3 wires, red, black and white.
Picture are below.
Can this oven be safely hooked up or do we need to upgrade the power supply? Obviously removing the power cord it was delivered with.
[

Sorry and here is a picture of the house wires.

The problem is the stove and house is using the old unsafe NEMA 10 type circuit.  It should be easy to upgrade the stove to NEMA 14 type.  The house circuit might be easy or hard depending how it goes though the house.  NEMA 14 adds a ground wire to the circuit which can protect/save you.

@crip659 It was hard-wired. There was no NEMA anything.

@nobody   Not NEMA, but NEMA 10 is easier to find by search.  The new oven does have NEMA 10 plug.

Are there any markings on the cable coming out of the wall?

Please supply: Old oven model # if you still have it. New oven model #. Picture of subpanel/breaker that controls the oven. How far is the oven from the subpanel?
